# Exhaust 98 Ford Expedition

Tags: exhaust

I need a complete exhaust system. Someone gave me 1. Not sure that it will fit my truck. How can I find out? It also includes a catylic converter. Mine currently has a hole in it. How do I find out if the catylic converter is strong enough to exhaust my engine? I’m probably not asking the right questions but it’s a start. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) which engine do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I would get the part numbers off the system you have just been given - a bit of research or seeing an exhaust place will tell which engine / model they match (you don’t mention engine type size)

Or you could remove the old one and lay both systems out and see if they match - not always conclusive as slight angle changes make a huge difference.